# How make ios lock screen in android app

Tags: android

I need some help. I need to do a screen similar to the screen lock ios 9. Here is an example of this screen:[image]
 If there are any lessons or ideas for the layout I will be glad.
 buttons I wanted to do through tablelayout and circle images, and paste text in them, but it may be better ideas

Comment: Your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question. 

StackOverflow is not a free code generator or tutorial site. Please seek assistance elsewhere should you require free source code.

Answer (score 1):

**@metalink** : I have implement this in android

### what should you do

```
  <RelativeLayout
    ... >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contain"
        ... android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >
        <!-- weightSum to 4 = whatever the screen, display 
             my children views in 4 sections -->
        <View
            ... android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_dots" />
        <!-- weight to 1 = this takes one section -->
        <View
            ... android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_dots" />
        <!-- weight to 1 = this takes one section -->
        <View
            ... android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_dots" />
        <View
            ... android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/green_dots" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/contain" ... >
        ... Here display your buttons (or textviews) with 
            custom drawable background for each one
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Then in your methods inside this Activity:**

```
 // init your buttons var
Button one, two, three, four, five ...;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set the layout above
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // init your buttons
    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    ... etc.

    // set them to your implementation
    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
    ... etc.
}

// call this function when one button is pressed
public void onClick(View view) {
    // retrieves the id of clicked button
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
             methodToSaveNumber(int);
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
             methodToSaveNumber(int);
        break;
        case R.id.button3:
             methodToSaveNumber(int);
        break;
        ... etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting info: German court just invalidated Apple's slide-to-unlock patent. It is sometimes a good idea not to copy a view 1:1, though this time Apple lost the patent on that. Good luck ;)

[germany-slide-to-unlock](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/08/25/germany-slide-to-unlock/)